# Constructing a graph with only triangles

Tags: graph-theory, algorithms

Given a set of points in the plane, is there an algorithm to connect the points such that the resulting graph only consists of triangles?

Answer (score 0):

*One* possible solution that I've found (and which works fine for my application) is the [Delaunay triangulation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Delaunay_triangulation).